# How can I implement XMPP protocol for my own chat client?

Tags: java, api, xmpp, chat

I want to write a chat client. I could use RMI for that but I don't want to. Moreover I plan to have a web-interface.

I was reading about XMPP protocol and also the fact that *google talk* uses it. How can I implement it to write my own chat client, not a client for any other IM service? Is there any library available that could help me implement my own chat service *(IM)* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [**Smack**](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). Its widely used and mature library for writing xmpp application. Here is an [example](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking-tutorials/551-how-write-simple-xmpp-jabber-client-using-smack-api.html) of writing xmpp client. Here is [one more example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/xmpp-im-with-smack-for-java.html).

Comment: Does it allow me to write my own IM messenger from scratch ?

Comment: Yes it does. The second link points to simplified client example.

Comment: If you could look at the query I left in the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34976/discussiom-between-suhail-and-santosh

Comment: Do I need [spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/) for my chat application ?

Comment: Spark is ready made chat application. If you are trying to build your own, you don't need spark.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries available on the xmpp site iteself. You can choose anyone based on your requirement [XMPP Libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/)
Go for [SMACK](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) if you are writing your IM in JAVA.

Comment: Lots of libraries, but none for Swift.

Comment: @User [Swift xmpp client](https://swift.im/)

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar neat. this must be new, since my comment.